# Sum large numbers in for loop while scraping data from other website

Tags: php, arrays

I have code where I'm scraping data from other web site, but data is large and contains lot of numbers. I'm trying to find solution to sum all that numbers but still failing.

That's the web **scraper** I use:

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://website.test/');
$webDoc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); //disable libxml errors
if(!empty($url)) { 
   $webDoc->loadHTML($url);
   libxml_clear_errors();
   $urlData = new DOMXPath($webDoc);
   $row = $urlData->query('//span[@class="stat_now_big"]');

   for ($i = 1; $i <= 114; $i += 6) {
        $getVal[$i] = str_replace( ',', '', $row->item($i)->nodeValue);
   }

$GetUnique= $getVal[1];
$data = [
    'unique' => number_format($GetUnique)
];
echo json_encode($data);
```

So, how can I Sum **$getVal[$i]** 20 times? I don't want to make it like **$total = $getVal[1] + $getVal[7] + $getVal[13]** and so on ...

What's the best way to get total amount from that data without making large code?

Comment: fefore for loop you should define variable with value 0 like this $total = 0; and inside your for lool you should use like this $total  = $total + $getVal[$i]; when you echo $total outside(bellow) loop, you will get total properly.

Answer (score 0):

You need a reducer.

```js
$rows = $urlData->query('//span[@class="stat_now_big"]');

// assuming your str_replace yields a number

array_reduce($rows, function($acc, $row) {
  return $acc + str_replace(',', '', $row->nodeValue);
}, 0)
```

I can't remember if the `DOMNodeList` type will be iterable by `array_reduce`, but if not there might be a way to convert it into an array first. My php specific language is rusty ‍♂️